# codeigniter 4 set session variable $session = \Config\Services::session(); globally

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

in codeigniter 4 as per the [documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/sessions.html) we have to load library as

$session = \Config\Services::session();

if i write it on above of controller name

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

    $session = \Config\Services::session();

    class Home extends BaseController
    {

    }
```

i cant access $session variable in any function, even if i wrote it in __construct it is not accessible in any function if i write it any function then only it is working, but i wants to set it globally.

Answer (score 4):

Initiate the session globally on the Base Controller in the "initController" function

```
$this->session = \Config\Services::session();
```

Use it anywhere

```
$this->session->set('title','value');
```

Answer (score 2):

i solved it, as below

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;




class Home extends BaseController
{

    protected $session;


    function __construct()
    {

        $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
        $this->session->start();


    }



    public function code4()
    {

        $newdata = [
                'username'  => 'johndoe',
                'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                'logged_in' => TRUE
        ];

        $this->session->set($newdata); // setting session data


        echo $this->session->get("username");

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Comment: Yep that will do it. You don't need to call the session start. WHEN you try to call session vars in your views - use the Common.php "helper" session(); read up on it.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw do you have any reference to the Common.php "helper" session() you mention? I didn't get anything helpful back from Google. Thank you!

Comment: @user752746 you can actully find the code and comments in the actual file itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `session()` anywhere you want.
It is a convenience method for accessing the session instance or an item that has been set in the session.

```
session(); // instantiate the session class
```

If you don't pass a string argument it returns a session class instance. It will return a shared instance if it exists or return a newly created instance if it does not.

Once a session is instantiated using the superglobal `$_SESSION` is the most efficient way to set session data.

```
$_SESSION['username']  = 'johndoe';
$_SESSION['email']     = 'johndoe@some-site.com';
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
```

Pass a string argument to retrieve saved session data

```
$userName = $session('username');
```

Or, you can use `Session` methods like this.

```
$session = session();
$userName = $session->get('username');
```

You don't have to load a "helper" in order to use `session()` is always loaded and available.

Comment: Thanks. The middle part of your coding is a little off the track. But The first and the last part is awesome. It worked like magic and now I don't have to use the session variable and class again and again

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is use like this:

```
`session()->get('name');// With this you can use any session value anywhere in the application `
```